# On Windows, can data in memory ever exist continuously across virtual memory pages?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

On Windows, can data in memory ever exist continuously across virtual memory pages?

For example,

- The string "hello", where "he" on one page and "llo" is on the next.
- Any large block of data that exceeds max page size, if possible.

Comment: "Page" refers to blocks of virtual memory addresses, so by definition, the answer is yes. I think you meant physical memory blocks, however.

Comment: Thanks, Robin and Adam. In that case, I was thinking about virtual memory pages.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that doesn't clear things up. Were you thinking about their contiguity with respect to their *virtual addresses*, or their *physical addresses*?

Comment: Virtual addresses. I'm sorry if I am not clear enough. I'll explain what I'm doing if that helps. I use VirtualQueryEx to walk through pages, then I want to search for maybe "hello" with ReadProcessMemory. If the whole "hello" can be on two different pages, I need to take this into consideration and it makes it somewhat more complicated. Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VirtualQueryEx` doesn't return individual pages, but ranges of pages having the same access.  If you're asking whether a string could span two pages with different access, theoretically yes, but this would in general be VERY rare.  It's more likely that the string you want is swapped out to disk.

Comment: Aah.. I was thinking about them as individual pages. Well, I feel a little stupid now for asking the wrong question, and even misunderstanding how it works. I apologize. I don't even deserve that up-vote. I would have liked to choose both your answer and JosephH's answer because if he meant ranges of pages the way I did, I don't think he was all wrong (but I am no expert). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe someone can please make my question explode into a million pieces of glittery magic? Hehe. :)

Answer (score 4):

Of course.

Memory pages might not appear contiguously in physical memory, but through the magic of virtual memory your program is none the wiser.